# React, click outside event happens right after click to open, preventing the modal from showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On button click I want the `Modal` to appear.
The `Modal` component adds a `eventListener` so it closes when you click outside the modal. In React 18 the click event triggers because the button click that happend **before** Modal was rendered? If I change to react 17 this does not happen.

Find a CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-mopsa-lgke69?file=/src/App.js). Notice,
when you click the button the `show` state sets to true.
Then the `Modal` component renders and calls the close function directly.

App.js:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const close = () => {
    setShow(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button
        onClick={(e) => {
          setShow(true);
        }}
      >
        Click
      </button>
      {show && <Modal close={close} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Modal.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Modal({ close }) {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleOutsideClick = (e) => {
      if (!ref?.current?.contains(e.target)) {
        console.log("This one gets called because of the button click", e);
        close();
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick, false);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick, false);
    };
  }, [close]);

  return (
    <div ref={ref} className="Modal">
      <h1>I'm a Modal!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @Benny. Did you find any solution for this question?

Comment: Here is a reply from Dan Abramov: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24657#issuecomment-1150119055

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call [event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to prevent multiple click handlers capturing the same click event.

```
    onClick={(e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      setShow(true);
    }}
```

I don't know why this would differ between React 17 and 18. React uses its own "synthetic events", and there might have been a change in how event propagation/bubbling happens between the two versions.

It might be connected to what's called "automatic batching" in React 18.
https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21

In your example, the Modal component uses native event handling with `document.addEventlistener()`. It seems that React 18 handles the click inside the app, which triggers a state change and a rerender, mounts the `Modal` component, runs the `useEffect()` hook, and creates the new event listener before the click event is propagated to the window node. In React 17, the event presumably finishes propagating before the re-render happens.

Comment: hm was a bit surprised the event listener captured the button click, because click happened before the listener was registered

Answer (score 2):

Dan Abramov gives some suggestions in this comment (https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24657#issuecomment-1150119055).

Suggestion 1 is: In the useEffect, delay the addEventListener call with a setTimeout with 0 wait time. Example:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleOutsideClick = (e) => {
      if (!ref?.current?.contains(e.target)) {
        console.log("This one gets called because of the button click", e);
        close();
      }
    };

    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      document.addEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick, false);
    }, 0);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      document.removeEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick, false);
    };
  });
```

Suggestion 2 is to capture the current event and ignore just that one in the modal's useEffect. Example provided by @YoussoufOumar in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72316017/7923169) and at https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/pull/18323

Answer (score -1):

You could change your `if` statement in `handleOutsideClick` as below. Yours is not working because the `button` for opening the `Modal`, since it's not inside the `Modal`, passes this
`if(!ref?.current?.contains(e.target))` you have.

[Here is a working fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-bird-qp7433?file=/src/App.js)  of your CodeSandbox. I'm passing the button's `ref` to `Modal`. And here is what I changed:

```js
const handleOutsideClick = (e) => {
  if (!ref?.current?.contains(e.target) && !openButtonRef?.current?.contains(e.target)) {
    console.log("This one gets called because of the button click", e);
    close();
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

A different solution to the problem involves new `startTransition` API: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-benz-0ey6ol?file=/src/App.js:340-388

```
onClick={(e) => {
  startTransition(() => {
    setShow(true);
  })
}}
```

This new API ([doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#starttransition)) definitely helps, but I'm not sure this is a legit solution, and docs are not quite clear on that. Would be nice if someone from React can comment -- is this an abuse?